# NetBeans - How to show all Swing components in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm making a Swing GUI with NetBeans, using the built-in form maker, which works quite well.

However, if I accidentally put the wrong panel on a form, I have no way to delete it, or select it again.

Likewise, if I want a button to open a new window, say, a file chooser, I don't know how to add that file chooser to the form, but not have it appear until the button is pressed.

Does anyone have any experience with the NetBeans Swing form builder? This seems like a common thing to have to do, but I don't see how to do it. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the wrong forum for such questions

Comment: I'm sorry, I've seen other questions about NetBeans functionality around here so I thought I would ask it, as it has been bothering me, and now completely halting my progress. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yay a netbeans user!Yea there should be a navigator window in the bottom left corner. There it displays all of the components on the form. Im not too sure what you mean by a file chooser, but to open a new window,ie another Jform, you create another form class. Then you create that form and setVisible.

So lets say you have 
a form **mainProgram**
And form **helpMenu**

In the **mainProgram**

```
public mainProgram(){
 InitComponents();//or something on the lines of that
 helpMenu helpMenuWindow = new helpMenuWindow();
 helpMenu.setVisible(true);
}
```

This will allow you to be able to open new windows, but if you click on the red X to close the window, it closes your whole program. In properties for the helpMenu pane you can select the option for what the window should do on exit.

Exit

Hide

Do nothing
In the code above is the code that is run before the Jpane displays, if you want to show or hide items, just code

```
Object.setVisible(boolean);
```

I hope I answered your question Tetramputechture.

Comment: Thank you so much! That button really doesn't want to be seen. haha

Comment: Yeah! Stuff is going well now! (: @kyle_england